# What is the best way to reload a vuejs component when a prop is updated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

Firstly, I use a rng to generate some numbers to be passed into my api call

```
created() {
for (let i = 0; i < this.cellNumber; i++) {
  this.rng.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 671 + 1));
}
```

I assigned these to an array called rng. I am rendering a component called Cell using the v-for directive

```
    <div v-for="x in rng" :key="x">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <Cell class="cells" :id="rng[x - 1]"></Cell>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This should pass the element 'x' in rng to the Cell component, however, even though the numbers are generated they are not passed to the component. Although, if I manually populate the array with numbers then the elements are passed to the Cell component. What is the best way to get around this issue? I assume it is because the calculations finish after the component is rendered, but I do not know how to update the component once the prop changes. I tried using a watch but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: you means the component=`Cell` is not updated when props=`id` is changed?

Comment: This shouldn't be a reactivity issue- [Vue tracks `.push()` and recognizes when it's used to modify an array](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods).

Comment: What's the purpose of `rng[x - 1]`? This is subtracting 1 from the *index* of the array accessed, are you sure that's what you want here?

Comment: Having duplicate `id`s is invalid HTML. Attempting to access the `n`-th member of an array where `n` is bigger than array's length is invalid JavaScript. Last, but not least, using duplicate keys will break Vue's ability to track the items correctly. Provide valid code and Vue will work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with this line `:id="rng[x - 1]"`?

I recreated the example, and passing the element `x` to `Cell` seems relatively straightforward.

If you simply wanted to pass `x` as a `prop` then you would write:

```
<div v-for="x in rng" :key="x">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <Cell class="cells" :id="x"></Cell>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ride-iw818?file=/src/App.vue).

---

Since numbers generated are quite big, then this line would not work (element does not exist):

```
:id="rng[x - 1]" //if x is 231 ---> rng[230]
```

It is as if you tried to access the element with an `index` of 230, for example where there are only 10 elements.

---

**Note** that it is possible that the numbers will be duplicated - that is why using `x` as `key` is not a good idea. You can replace it with index, for example.

```
<div v-for="(x, index) in rng" :key="index">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <Cell class="cells" :id="x"></Cell>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about the way the array was being accessed properly, and the key trick is helpful too.